# Remote Desktop and Application sharing application

Tags: websocket, rdp, vnc

I intend to implement a windows application to share the desktop. I found several protocols and technologies that can use to implement the application

1. VNC
2. Remote Desktop Protocol
3. WebSocket
4. XSocket.net
5. Lync SDK
6. Citrix ICA protocol

I have a requirement to use **c#** for the work. Actually I didn't get enough resources(Tutorials) regarding last 3 technologies. What I need to ask is what is the best technology or protocol that I can use from first 3 technologies. It's my pleasure if you can suggests me if any other technology suitable than this.

Comment: How do WebSocket and XSocket.net fit there? The first is a web communication protocol, the second an application that implements that protocol.

Comment: web socket can be used with html 5 and Java script to create Remote Desktop Application. I just found some document about Xsocket.net. it says that it can be used for real-time data transferring.

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/streaming/screenshare/    this is one of the link

Answer (score 0):

XenDesktop 7.x has solved this problem for the enterprise desktops.  I.e. where your desktop is joined to an active directory domain.

[Trial software is available for download](https://www.citrix.com/downloads/xenapp/evaluations-and-trial-software.html).

[PluralSight have a detailed tutorial on the XenDesktop 7.](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/introduction-citrix-xendesktop-7)